# How to format a graphic size to better visualization?

Tags: r, image, plot, graph, size

I'm conducting a meta-analysis (MA). I used the standard R command to conduct the analysis. My MA has many studies to analyze.

**e.g.** 30 studies to make the pooled analysis. After the command of the forest plot, I click on zoom to see the graph. However, the graph occupies the entire screen and many data do not appear.
**For example**, only the middle of the graph appears, but the top and bottom do not appear.

I tried to understand the ggplot2 and images packages, but I did not succeed. 
How could fix this problem?

Comment: Which program are you using?  R Console? Jupyter Notebook?  Some other ?

Comment: *"click on zoom"* doesn't make sense to me as a "normal R user", I'm not familiar with non-standard interfaces and/or full UI/UX apps/gadgets. This question is a bit "meta" in its own, since without any anything more, we have no idea of your environment, your data, or your code. Please consider filling this question a little by including sample data (that we can use), minimal code, and expected/actual output differences. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: I'm using RStudio. But even when I type the command on the R console, the image that appears is cropped. I've tried the squaresize, fontsize, width and height function, but I did not succeed.